# Accessing post variables using Java Servlets

Tags: java, http, servlets

What is the Java equivalent of PHP's `$_POST`? After searching the web for an hour, I'm still nowhere closer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your `HttpServletRequest` object has a `getParameter(String paramName)` method that can be used to get parameter values.  http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 60):

Here's a simple example. I didn't get fancy with the html or the servlet, but you should get the idea.

I hope this helps you out.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/myServlet">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for the Servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    ....
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tel me how to get the POST request value in servlet page? I'm using $.ajax call not form action and XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: my Question        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068510/i-couldnt-get-the-post-value-in-servlet-page

Answer (score 26):

POST variables should be accessible via the request object: [HttpRequest.getParameterMap()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()). The exception is if the form is sending multipart MIME data (the FORM has **enctype="multipart/form-data"**). In that case, you need to parse the byte stream with a MIME parser. You can write your own or use an existing one like the Apache [Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) API.

Comment: Note: this answer predates the release of Servlet 3.0 and standard support for `multipate/form-data`. See the [Java EE 6 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) and/or [this blog post](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html)

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are correct but remember to use the name attribute in the input fields (html form) or you won't get anything. Example:

`<input type="text" id="username" /> <!-- won't work -->
    <input type="text" name="username" /> <!-- will work -->
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> <!-- will work too -->`

All this code is HTML valid, but using getParameter(java.lang.String) you will need the name attribute been set in all parameters you want to receive.

Answer (score 1):

For getting all post parameters there is Map which contains request param name as key and param value as key.

```
Map params = servReq.getParameterMap();
```

And to get parameters with known name normal

```
String userId=servReq.getParameter("user_id");
```

Comment: The type of `params` really should be `Map<String, String[]>`