# How to find out which HTML button was pushed in my servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, button

I am creating a registration form which contains two submit buttons.
I need to know which button is clicked in the form in my servlet code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222/accessing-post-variables-using-java-servlets).

So, in

```
String button1 = request.getParameter("button1");
String button2 = request.getParameter("button2");
```

the value which isn't null is the pressed button.

Or, if you want to use the same name for the two buttons you can set a different value

```
<input type="submit" name="act" value="delete"/>
<input type="submit" name="act" value="update"/>
```

Then

```
String act = request.getParameter("act");
if (act == null) {
    //no button has been selected
} else if (act.equals("delete")) {
    //delete button was pressed
} else if (act.equals("update")) {
    //update button was pressed
} else {
    //someone has altered the HTML and sent a different value!
}
```

Comment: how do i do this without making the type = "submit"? Is there way to do this with type="button"?

Answer (score 4):

Only the clicked button will be a successful control.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Something">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Something Else">
```

Then, server side, check the value of the action data.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code...**

In JSP File...

```
<form action="MyServ">
            <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="OK">
            <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="OK">
        </form>
```

In Servlet File..

```
if (request.getParameter("btn1") != null){
       // do something
 }
else if (request.getParameter("btn2") != null){
       // do something
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can add a hidden field to the form and when a user clicks a button set its value to "btn1" or "btn2" using javascript before sumbit.

Cheers :)

Comment: There is no need for JS.  You can just do what Google does, have two submit buttons with different values.

Comment: <input name="submit" type="submit" value="SearchSumbit" onClick="
javascript: document.Form1.sumbitType.value = 'btn1';" />

BTW this is the JS way of doing it :)

Comment: So little code. So many things wrong with it. (1) It can't decide if it wants to be HTML or XHTML. (2) It has spelling errors. (3) It introduces a dependency on JS that simply isn't needed. (4) It uses a loop label without a loop. (5) It goes the long way around to get a reference to the form element. (6) It uses intrinsic event handler attributes instead of separating out the code in to a script file. While it is *a* way of doing it with JS, it is a very poor example of using JS to solve the problem, and JS is the wrong tool to solve the problem with in the first place.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen No, you are wrong. If you site is internationalized, you cannot depend on the value coming through in a reasonable form. The multiple submit buttons with different values idea is a non-starter for internationalized sites.