# Understanding how a submit button works and to check if another button has been pressed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, weblogic

I have a jsp that has 3 buttons, "check", "submit" and "cancel"
However I don't understand how the buttons works since there's no 'onclick' parameter.

Submit and Cancel buttons:

```
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
<input
                type="button" name="Submit3" value="Cancel"
                onClick="cancelConfirm('Are you sure?',
                                '/test/inbox.do?refresh=true&method=viewWorkItems')"></td>
```

I found a submit form function:

```
    function submitForm() {

    document.testFunc.method = "get";
    document.testFunc.action = "/test/page2.do?check=Y";
    document.getElementsByName('check')[0].click(); // < I specially don't understand this line.

}
```

Somewhere else I have the third button:

```
<input type="submit" name="check" value="Get Check"/></td>
```

How do the buttons work?  Since they are of type 'submit' they trigger the code on the submitForm() every time?

Is there a way to check if a button was pressed on the java side of things? I would be interested into looking if the check button was pressed since I need to display an error if that's the case when the submit button is pressed. 
Currently I'm trying to solve the problem with a boolean, but I don't really know how to see if the check button was pressed so I can change the boolean to true.

Is this what's doing the magic? - calling the step2.do when a submit button is pressed?

```
<form:form action="/test/step2.do" id="listForm" method="POST" onSubmit="return validateTest() " modelAttribute="searchTest" name="listForm">
```

Comment: What's the code of cancelConfirm ?

Comment: Buttons of `type='submit'` just submit automatically when clicked (assuming they're in an actual `form`)...you don't have to write any code to make them work.

Comment: I don't think your `submitForm()` function is ever even being called unless its referenced in your `form` tag's `onSubmit` attribute....

Comment: possible duplicate [How to find out which HTML button was pushed in my servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054543/how-to-find-out-which-html-button-was-pushed-in-my-servlet)

Comment: @developerwjk, but then what code gets executed? (which function?)

Comment: @developerwjk, is this what you are refering to: <form:form action="/test/step2.do" id="listForm"
  method="POST" onSubmit="return validateTest() "
  modelAttribute="searchTest" name="listForm">

Comment: @Rambo, I tried doing this one but back on the java code I don't seem to have the references (or I don't know how to get them) I don't have a 'request' so I can get the references from it.

Comment: When you click a submit button the only code being called is whatever is in your form's onsubmit attr, so `return validateTest()`.

Comment: You need to look into ajax, since it sounds like you want to do backend validation without changing pages.