# How to extract parameters from a restful post request using jersey and convert it into parameterized form?

Tags: java, rest, curl, jersey, jax-rs

I have a curl post restful request:

```
curl -i -X POST -d "debit_user_id=/customer/mobile_number:917827448775&recipient_id=/customer/mobile_number:9988776655/recipients/mobile_number:917526337452&pintwin=1234&amount=5000&currency=INR&customer_id=/customer/mobile_number:9988776655&agent_id=/agents/mobile_number:919987536699" https://api.eko.co.in/transactions
```

How can I extract these parameters coming in the request body using jersey JAX-RS, and how to test this using a java restful API client. My final aim is to convert this request into a parameterized form and send it to my another servlet.

Comment: Can't you look at that curl and figure out what the URL and request parameters are?

Comment: I can, but my problem is the request will be by my client and it will be hitting my jersey servlet. There i need to extract these parameters and convert them into a parameterized URL format. In my servlet how can i extract the parameters from the post request body

Comment: There are ample resources out there for how to extract POST parameters, such as [this helpful SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222/accessing-post-variables-using-java-servlets).