# Servlet doPost obtain JSON

Tags: java, json, servlets, post, request

I would like to retrieve the following information from a JSON:

```
{
    "list_folder": {
            "accounts": [
                        "dbid:Aapamskfpano1-l2_12oKKn123o1pk23"
                        ]
    },
    "delta": {
            "users": [
                      12321512
            ]
    }
```

}

I need both the accounts array and users array. This JSON is in the body.

How I can obtain and parse this?

Comment: but you mean retrieve the JSON in the controller or in the client side by javascript?

Comment: [`ServletRequest::getReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to retrieve the JSON in the doPost method in the server side.

Comment: @Lechucico are you using some framework like spring?

Comment: @cralfaro I'm just using java servlets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing post variables using Java Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222/accessing-post-variables-using-java-servlets)

Comment: Obtaining this JSON and parsing it are two separate questions that both have been addressed on SO.

Comment: This JSON is in the body, not a POST parameter.

Comment: @Lechucico have a look here, is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-json-post-data

Answer (score -2):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Also, please indent your code blocks.