# Java Servlet doPost() returning null from Postman

Tags: java, post, servlets, postman

I am doing a simple `Java Servlet` `POST request` without using any `HTML` and only using `Postman`. And the response from `getParameter()` is always `null`.

Here is the servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/api/form")
public class FormServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String orderNumber = req.getParameter("testString");
        System.out.println(orderNumber);
        resp.getWriter().print(orderNumber);
    }
}
```

And a picture with responses and how I am doing it:

[image]

**EDIT**

As was commented by Mukesh Verma.

All I had to do was add `@MultipartConfig` Annotation and I got the data.

Comment: What if you pass in `"test"` as opposed to `test`?

Comment: @npinti same result

Comment: @npinti How would that help? That's not what's sent in a form request.

Comment: Can you show the request "Headers" tab?

Comment: Try using @MultipartConfig Annotation. It handles form-data mime type.

Comment: @MukeshVerma that did it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not how method `getParameter` works. As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter), you should call the servlet with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/form?testString=test
```

Comment: It does return "test", but is there no way to get it working with Postman's form-data?

Comment: Try changing Postman's radiobutton from `form-data` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: It doesn't have to be `getParameter()` but is there a way to get the data from the request?

Comment: It still returns null

Comment: @kataroty Try `getParameterMap()` to see if you get anything

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222/accessing-post-variables-using-java-servlets set Postman to `form-data` and access the using `getParametersMap`

Comment: Try using @MultipartConfig.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @MultipartConfig Annotation. It handles form-data mime type.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Postman's radiobutton from form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded also does the trick and I am able to get the data.